# Insert into the second column of CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

When I do like this

```
        list.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT,0,left,0,0,0,NULL);
    list.InsertItem(LVIF_TEXT,1,right,0,0,0,NULL);
```

It inserts string "right" under "left".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CListCtrl::SetItemText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sya0wk5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is your friend

```
int nItem = list.InsertItem(0, _T("1st column"));
list.SetItemText(nItem, 1, _T("2nd column"));
```

Comment: This is a great workaround, but I'm still unsure why it is necessary. Why doesn't InsertItem() set the text properly? Is this a known MFC bug?

Comment: Because an item is actually a row: A set of columns, possibly an image, an image overlay, some state info,... There is no bug in there: Calling InsertItem() twice creates 2 items, that is: 2 rows. One could only have wished that InsertItem() could take an array of texts to fill all columns in on call. It does not. Not optimal but also not a bug.